# How to expand variables with fmt.Println()

Tags: go, println, gofmt

I can't expand variables with fmt.Println().

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main(){
  old := 20
  fmt.Println("I'm %g years old.",old)
}
```

result =>

```
I'm %g years old.
20
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'export'? Please show us a full example of what you are trying to achieve and where it fails.

Comment: 1) There's a missing semicolon

Comment: 2) Println doesn't format, that's what Printf and family are for.

Comment: Sorry, 'export' is typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Printf` not `Println`. Use `%d` for `old` which is type `int`. Add a newline.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    old := 20
    fmt.Printf("I'm %d years old.\n", old)
}
```

Output:

```
I'm 20 years old.
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation for `fmt.Println`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) states, this function does not support format specifiers. Use [`fmt.Printf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf) instead.